# Pinned Posts Modeling: having pinned flag column inside "posts" table VS having pinned_posts table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, database-performance

## Context

I have implemented a basic posting system in Rails, hence, I have a "posts" table with the following columns: id, user_id, body, created_at, updated_at.

I would like to enable users to pin their posts (only one post at a time, so a has_one relationship)

## Question

I see two ways of implementing this:

- adding a "pinned" boolean column inside the "posts" table
- adding a "pinned_posts" table with the following columns: id, user_id, post_id, created_at, updated_at

**What are the Pros and Cons of above two ways ?**

Answer (score 0):

Because you are limiting to one post per user, you could have the `post_id` filled in or `NULL` in the `Users` table.

This enforces the 1-per-user rule and has (perhaps) minimal overhead.

You have not said what happens to pinned posts; there could be other issues.  Do you need to find all pinned posts (would require a costly scan of `Users`)?  Do you want to flag a particular post when displaying user info?  (That will be quite efficient.)

May I suggest you learn some of the basics of Databases; third party software ("R", in this case) can't really shield programmers from database concepts.

Comment: Hi Rick, thank you for your answer!

I have two concerns about adding post_id to the users table.
1) users table would have one new attribute that is not directly related to the user entity.
2) If we suppose that I pick-up this strategy for any 1-per-user relation, I would end with a users table full of NULL columns


To answer to your question, yes I need to retrieve all pinned posts. And, flagging a particular post was what I meant by "adding a "pinned" boolean column inside the "posts" table" ( I am not sure if we are talking about the same thing here ??)